# Haskell requires more memory than Python when I read map from file. Why?

Tags: haskell, io, hash-map, unicode, memory-optimization

I have this simple code in Python:

> ```python
> input = open("baseforms.txt","r",encoding='utf8')
> S = {}
> for i in input:
>     words = i.split()
>     S.update( {j:words[0] for j in words} )
> print(S.get("sometext","not found"))
> print(len(S))
> ```

It requires 300MB for work. "baseforms.txt" size is 123M.

I've written the same code in Haskell:

```haskell
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import qualified Data.Map as M
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as B
import Data.Text.Lazy.Encoding(decodeUtf8)
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy as T
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy.IO as I
import Control.Monad(liftM)

main = do
    text <- B.readFile "baseforms.txt"
    let m = (M.fromList . (concatMap (parseLine.decodeUtf8))) (B.lines text)
    print (M.lookup "sometext" m)
    print (M.size m)
    where
        parseLine line = let base:forms = T.words line in [(f,base)| f<-forms]
```

It requires 544 MB and it's slower than Python version. Why? Is it possible to optimise Haskell version?

Data file can be downloaded [here](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/5eb11b6cb6d7/baseforms.txt)

I've tried non-lazy version of Data.Text and Data.Text.IO - memory usage is near 650MB

I've also tried hashtables, but  memory usage growth up to 870 MB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't seem to download your data set. Could you re-upload a smaller dataset (say, ~5mb? and with your testing statistics for it) to Pastebin or somewhere?

The only obvious performance difference with your Python version is that `Data.Map` is based on a binary tree, whereas Python's dict is a hashtable. This makes `fromList` an O(n * log n) operation in Haskell (unless you luck into the fact that your list of `(form, base)` pairs happen to all be distinct and sorted in ascending order) but constructing the Python dict is O(n). This should make a significant time difference, but not necessarily space, so at this point I'm out of ideas. Make sure you're compiling with `-O2` I guess.

(There also seems to be a functional difference between your two versions if my understanding of Python hasn't rusted off after years of neglect. `{j:words[0] for j in words}` will pair `words[0]` with itself, so maybe you want `parseLine` to be defined as `let forms@(base:_) = ...`.)

On issues of style, see the below rewrite. Note particularly the reordering of definitions so as to eliminate the `where`-clause. In your version it was easy to miss due to being inline with the `do`-block, you can do as I did, or try decreasing the indent.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import qualified Data.Map             as Map
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as ByteString
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy       as Text
import           Data.Text.Lazy.Encoding (decodeUtf8)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    text <- fmap decodeUtf8 $ ByteString.readFile "baseforms.txt"
    let parseLine line = let (base:forms) = Text.words line
                         in  zip forms (repeat base)
        m = Map.fromList . concatMap parseLine . Text.lines $ text
    print $ Map.lookup "sometext" m
    print $ Map.size m
```

Comment: [Beginning with GHC 6.12, text I/O is performed using the system or handle's current locale and line ending conventions](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.0.4/docs/Data-Text-IO.html)

My locale encoding is not utf8, but file in utf8

Comment: Huh, so it does. I'm getting to my dotage I guess.

Comment: Wow, memory usage decreased to `467 MB total memory in use (26 MB lost due to fragmentation)` with new version :)

Comment: Progress! I think that is probably due to fusion, `Text.lines` isn't subject to fusion so it helps to decode first as decoding *is* subject to fusion. Try switching to `Data.Map.Strict` next, I suspect that the `Map` is accumulating a whole pile of thunks to small `Text` values. You shouldn't need to change anything but the import line.

Comment: Switch to `Data.Map.Strict` have no effect, but switching to strict `Text` and `ByteString` decreased memory usage to `374 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)` - thank you for your help!

Comment: Interesting! I did not expect that. Glad I could be of assistance though.